# Problem to use µTorrent

Tags: 14.04, utorrent, torrent-client

I'm with problem to install µTorrent I used this command in this [link](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/08/install-utorrent-in-ubuntu-fedora/)

And appear this message

[image: here]

I want to make download files in thepiratebay.se but the most files it can't be make using bit torrent in Magnet Links.

There other way to install Magnet Links?

Or how can I fix this problem with my µTorrent?

Comment: Is there a reason you want the settings in `/opt`? Doing so would require you to use `sudo`. Also, note that most bittorrent clients now can use magnet links.

Comment: Ok @saiarcot895 but whats bittorrent clients can I have to make download on Ubuntu?

Comment: In KDE, there's kTorrent. There's also qBittorrent, which uses Qt (works for any distro). There's also Transmission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

µtorrent is working properly, there is nothing you should worry about this message. Please, read the page you gave us further ("To access utorrent server" is the part you want to read).

Comment: how can I find this page for I read?

Comment: You gave the link yourself : http://www.howopensource.com/2011/08/install-utorrent-in-ubuntu-fedora/. Just scroll down a few.